# WPF window inside WinForms: memory is not freed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, memory

i have a memory issue when I open a WPF Window inside a WinForms Window. 
Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MemoryTester.MainWindow wpf_window;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        wpf_window = new MemoryTester.MainWindow())
        wpf_window.Closed += Wpf_window_Closed;
        wpf_window.Show();

    }
}
```

It opens correctly but when I close the window it seems that the allocated memory is not freed. The allocated process memory in Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools shows that when I open the window the number rises by ~20MB but never reaches the level before after the window is closed. Same in Task Manager when I start the program without Visual Studio.

Since a Wpf window has no Dispose() method I tried catching the closed event and doing things like this:

```
    private void Wpf_window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        wpf_window.Closed -= Wpf_window_Closed;

        wpf_window.Close();

        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Still the same behavior.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you even worry about freeing the memory? The framework takes care of it sooner or later.

Comment: The WPF window that you created might be too large to get into the ''classic'' heap and be instead be allocated into the LOH `LargeObjectHeap`. The LOH will expand if it cannot contain the new object. But when an object in the LOH is destroyed, it does not immediately reduce it's size. And AFAIK won't try to do it unless there is a heavy strain on your computer's memory. You can try to use a memory profiler before the WPF window is open, while it is open and after you closed it to check how is your application's allocated memory used

Comment: Is this the actual code? Your closed handler implies the wpf_window reference is kept somehwere?

Comment: You are right, I updated the code above.

Comment: As wpf_window is a member of Form1 you need to set it to null one you're finished using it (after the window is closed). Better yet, get rid of the class member and define it locally inside the button1_click function and then in Wpf_window_Closed cast 'sender' to MainWindow. The sender argument here is a reference to your wpf window.

Comment: Or use a local variable and remove the closed handler entirely, it doesn't do anything useful.  Calling `Close` on a window that's already closed won't do anything, and `GC.Collect` is not necessary.

Comment: @emkay360 I should have said kept "alive"

Comment: You mean the EventHandler keeps a reference to the Winforms and therefore prevents the WpfWindow to be collected? I thought desubscribing to the event would solve this problem.
Anyway, even without the Eventhandler the memory does not change...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the using statement?

```
using(wpf_window = new MemoryTester.MainWindow()){
    wpf_window.Closed += Wpf_window_Closed;
    wpf_window.Show();}
```